# Documentation on creating a spring-security-oauth2 client using java config

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0

has anyone seen a good documentation on integrating oauth2 with a spring security application using java config?

I'm currently trying to add oauth using github as provider and all I can find are a lot of very specific examples. The official documentation unfortunately seems not to be very much up to date here.

Any pointers are welcome. Links to good documentation as well as simple snippets if that's all it takes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a lot of JavaConfig samples for all sorts of OAuth2 functionality in [github repo for spring-security-oauth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation). These are organized as tests but do demonstrate various features and functionality.

Also, here's the [sparklr-boot example application](https://github.com/dsyer/sparklr-boot) with JavaConfig by Dave Syer.